# Is it safe to remove Path variable for Delphi Rad studio 10

Tags: delphi, path, oracle11g

I have to install Oracle Client. In order to do it I need to update a value of the path. 
My current Path has a value for Delphi: 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Bpl.

Do you think I can delete the current value without causing any problems for Delphi?

Here is the error I got from Oracle client:
Expected Value
 : 1023
Actual Value
 : 1226
 List of errors:
 -

PRVF-3929 : Adding the Oracle binary location to the PATH environment variable will exceed the OS length limit of [ "1023" ] for the variable on the node "HQTPDZAJAW7" 
 - Cause:  The installer needs to update the PATH environment variable to include the value "%ORACLE_HOME%/bin;". However, doing so will cause PATH to exceed the maximum allowable length that this operating system allows.  - Action:  Ensure that the sum of the lengths of your current PATH environment variable and that of "%ORACLE_HOME%/bin;" does not exceed the operating system limit. Restart the installer after correcting the setting for environment variable.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should try it and if it causes any problems for Delphi, you can just set the value back...

Comment: What version of Oracle Client are you installing? This limit hasn't existed since around Windows 95, IIRC. It certainly isn't the limit on XP/Win2K/Vista/Win7 or any of the Windows Server editions.

Comment: Oracle Client 64bit 11g I have downloaded recently from the website. I have installed a new version(3.3) of Quest Toad Data Point. I was advised by its support to install Oracle Client to make Toad more stable by using TNS connection instead of direct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete that entry from your system path variable. Note that if you do then any packages that you compile, that have their .bpl files written to that directory, will not be found at runtime. If that does not matter to you then fine, remove that directory from your path.

I would comment however, that there is no `1023` character limit on the length of an environment variable. The limits are described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx